# Форма обратной связи, разделенная на две части

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Такой вопрос, если мне нужно сделать часть полей ввода в одной части страницы, а часть полей ввода и кнопку сабмина совсем в другой части страницы, и при этом это должна быть одна форма, чтобы при клике на сабмит данные собирались как из верхних полей, так и из нижних в один запрос и отправлялись на сервер, каким образом это можно реализовать?

Comment: а в чем вы видите проблему ?

Comment: 1. мне еще с таким не приходилось сталкиваться 2. не понимаю, как это можно реализовать, если у меня сначала должна идти часть полей, потом много других дивов, не относящихся к форме, а потом еще часть полей и кнопка сабмита.

Comment: Другие элементы страницы можно писать внутри тега <form>. Правда к ним применятся стили формы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если внутри формы нет других форм — все нормально и можно напихать дивы внутрь формы (в основном так делают, если дивы относятся к форме, к примеру WYSIWYG редактор).

Зачем Вам так делать? Это может быть нарушением основных принципов юзабилити, и еще, и еще...  Ищите ошибки в макете.

Если внутри формы есть другая форма — у вас однозначно ошибка в дизайне.

Comment: Нет, внутри формы других форм нет, просто сначала идет несколько полей ввода, потом много других дивов с разной информацией, потом еще два поля и кнопка сабмита. Получается, все эти дивы будут напиханы внутрь формы? Ну а что касется зачем - ну дизайнер так нарисовал, что ж я сделаю.